# How to @Inject a third party class in JavaEE

Tags: jakarta-ee, dependency-injection

In the following example, how to inject a class from third-party library? For example

```
@Stateless
class MyStatelessService
{
@Inject Gson gson;
...
}
```

I suppose that I must create some bean injector class responsible for all third party classes. How to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would have to create a specialized producer for the type you want to inject. Perfect example already exists for you - it is a Logger injection using the weld extensions.

```
@Inject
Logger log;
```

You can have a look into the weld extension here:

https://github.com/weld/extensions/blob/master/impl/src/main/java/org/jboss/weld/extensions/log/

and the Producer.java itself here:

https://github.com/weld/extensions/blob/master/impl/src/main/java/org/jboss/weld/extensions/log/Producers.java